# Python: get key information from user's input

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am a totally new Python learner and am trying to write a Python script to analysis my simulation log file, but I am now having some problem get key information from user's input.

First of all, I started my script with:

```
op = raw_input("pls enter options")
```

To get user inputs. I am expected to get some input like:

```
"+addr=abcdef +tid=12 +time=135000"
```

**The question is:** how do I pick the key information and assign them into my variables? For example, sign `abcdef` into my Python variable `address = abcdef` and integer `12` to `transaction_id = 12`?

Additionally, the user is not necessary to give all options, for example: the user can only input `+time=135000`

The other variables that not declared are assigned zero, except variable `time = 135000`

Comment: Would it not be better to have command line arguments/options rather than user inputs? Something you could execute as `python myscript.py abcdef 12 135000` ? or `python myscript.py --addr=abcdef --tid=12 --time=135000`

Comment: You could use a regex to parse the input, but why don't you just prompt the user three times or use command line arguments?

Comment: @DainDwarf: Can you please explain how do do it, I am a totally new python learner. :(

Comment: @timgeb Well, I think that wastes quite lot time, becasue I will develop more options in the future.

Comment: Hmm...don't know what do you want to do...but `a = dict(i.split('=') for i in "+addr=abcdef +tid=12 +time=135000".strip('+').split(' +'))` may give you some ideas...and then there's a function called [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

Comment: @KevinGuan This might not work, because the order of the options is not fixed, therefore you may get wrong values for different variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing arguments from command line is done with argparse module:

`myscript.py` content:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse
    args = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    args.add_argument('--addr', type=str, default='0') #Are you sure you want a string '0'?
    args.add_argument('--tid', type=int, default=0) #type=int will ensure user cannot input somethin other than an int
    args.add_argument('--time', type=int, default=135000) #Look at datetime module if you need a timestamp.

    options = args.parse_args() #Parses user command line

    print("My options where : " + str(options))
```

Then you can use your script like this:

```
$ python myscript.py 
My options where : Namespace(addr='0', tid=0, time=135000)

$ python myscript.py --help
usage: myscript.py [-h] [--addr ADDR] [--tid TID] [--time TIME]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  --addr ADDR
  --tid TID
  --time TIME

$ python myscript.py --addr=abcdef --tid=12 --time=135000
My options where : Namespace(addr='abcdef', tid=12, time=135000)
```

Comment: Ok I will try this one

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to call your script with command line arguments:

```
import sys

#Your code here...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = sys.argv
    address = args[1] #Starts at index 1, args[0] is the name of the script       
    id = args[2]
    tim = args[3]
```

When you call your script you'll specify the parameters like this:

```
python myScript.py  abcdef 12 135000
```

All your parameters will be strings.

Comment: Emm.. The problem is that users may not type those arguments in certain order.